# show one popover hide others bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have several images with unique popover. When a user click on one of them, I want the others to be hidden and only one is shown.

This what I have done so far. I have no ide on how to hide other popovers when one is active, thats what I need help with.

HTML/HAML:

```
%ul
  %li
    = image_tag 'robert-reco.jpg', class: "active ", id: "recorobert"
  %li
    = image_tag 'anan-reco.jpg', id: "recoanna" 
  %li
    = image_tag 'christian-reco.jpg', id: "recochristian"
  %li
    = image_tag 'hanjun-reco.jpg', id: "recohanjun"
```

Jquery code:

```
//popover homepage
    $('#recorobert').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        html : 'true',
        content : '<p>Text 1</p><p class="small">- Robert, kampanjen <a href="#">Movember är här</a></p>',
        trigger : 'click'
    });
    $('#recoanna').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        html : 'true',
        content : '<p>Text 2</p><p class="small">- Anna, kampanjen <a href="#">Varför apor aldrig bär rosa klänning</a></p>',
        trigger : 'click'
    }); 
    $('#recochristian').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        html : 'true',
        content : '<p>Text 3</p><p class="small">- Christian, kampanjen <a href="#">Varför apor aldrig bär rosa klänning</a></p>',
        trigger : 'click'
    });
    $('#recohanjun').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        html : 'true',
        content : '<p>Text 4</p><p class="small">- Adam, kampanjen <a href="#">Varför apor aldrig bär rosa klänning</a></p>',
        trigger : 'click'
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with HAML but try something like this in your click function:

```
$.each('li:not('.active')', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: when I click now on one of the div, it wont open the popover.

Comment: Are you getting errors or anything? Is the code I provided hiding the other images like you wanted? Also - You said the `div` won't open but you have the ID on the `li`'s was that just a typo?

Comment: the active css class for something else, no error just now that I click on the images nothing will happen. it would be very helpful if you could provide a jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:** When one popover is clicked use jquery to addclass hide to all the others, you need to remove this class once the user is done viewing to show all popovers again. it would looks something like this.

```
$(".allpopovers").addClass("hide");
$(this).removeClass("hide");
```

Comment: Or try that answer down there.